# MyBatis stored procedure call with optional parameters

Tags: mybatis

I wonder how could I describe in mybatis `xml` stored procedure call with optional parameters.
For example:

**DAO**

```
public List getMethod1(Object arg1) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("arg1", arg1);
        return selectList("myBatisSelect", map);
}

public List getMethod1(Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("arg1", arg1);
        map.put("arg2", arg2);
        return selectList("myBatisSelect", map);
}
```

**XML**

```
    <select id="myBatisSelect"
            parameterType="map"
            resultType="MyResultObject">
          CALL sql_stored_procedure
            (
                @arg1= #{arg1}
                <!-- How to add optional parameter here??-->
            )       

    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional logic to dynamically generate your sql.

i.e.

```
<select id="myBatisSelect"
        parameterType="map"
        resultType="MyResultObject">
      CALL sql_stored_procedure
        (
            @arg1= #{arg1}
            <if test="arg2 != null">
                    ,#{arg2}
            </if>
        )       

</select>
```

The [MyBatis3 User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf) has more information.